# c++ string iterator "find first of"

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Is there a method in string iterator like find_first_of on string ?
Something like:

```
string::iterator it;
string str("  h asdasf ^& saafa");
it = FIND_FIRST_OF("&az^");
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

And the result:

> a

Comment: Short answer: no. Iterators have a very narrow interface--mostly just dereference and `advance` (with members like `++` and `--` to do the advancing). You might consider using `std::regex`, which provides an iterator interface though.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it indirectly

```
auto pos = str.find_first_of("&az^");
```

then advance the iterator

```
if(pos != std::string::npos) // thanks to @Mike Seymour
    std::advance(it, pos);
```

I guess you can also do some kind of `std::find` with a lambda, but the above is really much more simpler and concise.

Comment: You'd better check that it's not `npos` first.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks, it was implicitly assumed :) Modified it anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `str[pos]` (The question is asking for a character, although it mentions 'iterator')

Comment: for( it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); it++ )
...
I have a for that, i would like to find a solution to change begin() to smth like: for( it = line.find_first_of("{[],}\""); it != line.end(); it++ )

Comment: @DieterLücking was not clear for me if OP wants an iterator or the position. If it's simply the position, then yes, `str[pos]` is enough.

Comment: @JohnMcCoy you cannot do it in one single loop, unless you use `std::find_first_of` as mentioned in the @QuestionC's answer. But the loop declaration becomes less elegant/clear, you should really split the declaration since it doesn't really buy you anything.

Answer (score 4):

I think `std::find_first_of` is what you're looking for.

```
string::iterator it;
string str("  h asdasf ^& saafa");
string find_me ("&az^");
it = std::find_first_of (str.begin(), str.end(), find_me.begin(), find_me.end());
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

I would write a function to clean up the overhead involved in constructing/using the intermediary find_me variable if using this method with any frequency.

Comment: That's another way, upvoted. You have some typos though, replace `;` by `,` in `find_first_of`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
std::string::size_type position = example.find_first_of(".");
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
  std::advance(string_iterator, position);
}
else
{
  string_iterator = example.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `std::string` has its own methods `find_first_of` and `find_last_of` apart from other find methods.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "  h asdasf ^& saafa" );
    auto pos = s.find_first_of( "&az^" );

    if ( pos != std::string::npos ) std::cout << s[pos] << std::endl;

    pos = s.find_last_of( "&az^" );

    if ( pos != std::string::npos ) std::cout << s[pos] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a
a
```

Here is another demonstrative program that finds all characters in the string that are specified in the character literal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "  h asdasf ^& saafa" );

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find_first_of( "&az^", pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          ++pos )
    {
        std::cout << pos << ": " << s[pos] << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4: a
7: a
11: ^
12: &
15: a
16: a
18: a
```

Knowing the found position you always can get the corresponding iterator in the object:

```
std::string::iterator it = std::next( s.begin(), pos );
```

or

```
auto it = std::next( s.begin(), pos );
```

or simply

```
std::string::iterator it = s.begin() + pos;
```

Also there is standard algorithm `std::find_first_of` declared in header `<algorithm>` that also can be used with objects of type std::string.